# Joining over multiple columns with best match

Tags: r

I have two example datasets:

```
data <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1:10)
  , COL1 = LETTERS[1:10]
  , COL2 = letters[1:10]
  , COL3 = as.character(10:1)
  , stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

match <- data.frame(
  COL1 = c("A", "C", "F", "*", "F")
  , COL2 = c("a", "c", "*", "*", "*")
  , COL3 = c("10", "8", "5", "*", "*")
  , VAL = c(0.8, 0.7, 0.9, 0.85, 0.1)
  , stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

They look like:

```
   > data
   ID COL1 COL2 COL3
1   1    A    a   10
2   2    B    b    9
3   3    C    c    8
4   4    D    d    7
5   5    E    e    6
6   6    F    f    5
7   7    G    g    4
8   8    H    h    3
9   9    I    i    2
10 10    J    j    1

> match
  COL1 COL2 COL3  VAL
1    A    a   10 0.80
2    C    c    8 0.70
3    F    *    5 0.90
4    *    *    * 0.85
5    F    *    * 0.10
```

> The result table should combine the `data` table with the `match`
>   table, so that the information in the `match` table fits best to the
>   rows in the `data` table. So if you look into the match table, there
>   are two different matches for the F in `COL1`. Because there is also a 5 in
>   `COL3`, the value 0.9 should be joined.

The result should look like:

```
   ID COL1 COL2 COL3  VAL
1   1    A    a   10 0.80
2   2    B    b    9 0.85
3   3    C    c    8 0.70
4   4    D    d    7 0.85
5   5    E    e    6 0.85
6   6    F    f    5 0.90
7   7    G    g    4 0.85
8   8    H    h    3 0.85
9   9    I    i    2 0.85
10 10    J    j    1 0.85
```

I wrote a workaround for this:

```
library(tidyverse)

col1u <- sort(unique(match$COL1))
col2u <- sort(unique(match$COL2))
col3u <- sort(unique(match$COL3))

dataTransformed <- data %>%
  mutate(COL1 = ifelse(COL1 %in% col1u, COL1, "*")
         , COL2 = ifelse(COL2 %in% col2u, COL2, "*")
         , COL3 = ifelse(COL3 %in% col3u, COL3, "*"))

dataJoin <- inner_join(dataTransformed, match)
```

This works fine but I wonder if this approach is too complicated because the real datasets have a lot more columns. Is there an easier solution?

Comment: You said `This works fine`, but the expected output is different by using your code.  Which one is the expected?

Comment: Hi @akrun, important for me is that the `ID` gets the correct `VAL` matches. It doesn't matter which values are in the other columns.

Comment: Ok, In that case, the below code should give the same as your `dataJoin`

Answer (score 0):

We could do

```
library(tidyverse)
match %>%
    summarise_at(vars(matches("COL")), funs(list(sort(unique(.))))) %>%
    map2_df(data[names(.)], ., ~ case_when(.x %in% .y[[1]] ~ .x, TRUE ~ "*")  ) %>% 
    bind_cols(data['ID'], .) %>% 
    inner_join(match)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! Can you generalise it so that the `COL` columns can have generic names? In my "real" dataset the columns names are different.

Comment: @FelixGrossmann  Can  it be due to position index?  In that case, you can do `summarise_at(2:4, funs(..`